# How to list directories only if there is no further subdirectory present using NIO in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, nio

I am using Java 8 NIO and the below code to list directories;

```
String  rootDir = "root\\";
Files.walk(Paths.get(rootDir)).filter(Files::isDirectory).forEach(folder_path -> {
    System.out.println(folder_path.toString());
});
```

But this will give the output like below;

```
root
root\dir1
root\dir1\subdir1
root\dir1\subdir2
root\dir2
root\dir2\subdir1
root\dir2\subdir2
root\dir3
root\dir3\subdir1
root\dir3\subdir2
```

But, I would like to display the path, only if there is no further sub-directories. So, the expected output will be like;

```
root\dir1\subdir1
root\dir1\subdir2
root\dir2\subdir1
root\dir2\subdir2
root\dir3\subdir1
root\dir3\subdir2
```

Is this possible? If yes, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

You can implement a filter straight-forwardly, e.g.

```
Files.walk(Paths.get(rootDir))
    .filter(Files::isDirectory)
    .filter(dir -> {
       try(Stream<Path> sub=Files.list(dir)) { return sub.noneMatch(Files::isDirectory); }
       catch(IOException ex) { throw new UncheckedIOException(ex); }
    })
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

which is simple but performs redundant operations on each encountered directory.

A more efficient alternative would be a classic loop solution:

```
Set<Path> dirs = new LinkedHashSet<>();
for(Iterator<Path> it = Files.walk(Paths.get(rootDir)).iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    Path p = it.next();
    if(Files.isDirectory(p) && dirs.add(p)) dirs.remove(p.getParent());
}
dirs.forEach(System.out::println);
```

It simply removes parent directories when encountering another directory, so at the end of this single iteration, only directories not containing other directories are left.

Or with the good old Java 7 API:

```
Files.walkFileTree(root, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
    Path previous;

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException exc) {
        if(previous == null || !previous.startsWith(dir))
            System.out.println(dir);
        previous = dir;
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }
});
```

By overriding `postVisitDirectory` (instead `preVisitDirectory`), we have visited a child directory of it right before, if there was one. So a simple test whether the previous path is a child of the current is sufficient.

Comment: The solution is really nice but I hate to try catch inside a stream since there is no error channel. I really hope they think about it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method to check sub-directory and add it in filter as below,

```
private static Predicate<Path> checkSubDirectory() {
    return f1->{
        for (File file : f1.toFile().listFiles()) {
            if (file.isDirectory())
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    };
}

Files.walk(Paths.get(rootDir)).filter(Files::isDirectory)
       .filter(checkSubDirectory())                      
       .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple version which uses streams:

```
LinkedHashSet<Path> dirs = new LinkedHashSet<>();
try(Stream<Path> stream = Files.find(dir, Integer.MAX_VALUE, (path,attr) -> attr.isDirectory())) {
    stream.filter(dirs::add).map(Path::getParent).forEach(dirs::remove);
}
```